# Is there an up-to-date map of street art in London?

Tags: london, maps, artworks

I'll be traveling to London soon and would like to have a look at some professional street art, such as the graffiti works by Banksy. Is there a continuously updated map somewhere that lists the location of such works?

Comment: The area around Camden lock is decorated.

Comment: While it's not a map, why don't you consider a tour such as http://www.freetoursbyfoot.com/london-tours/walking-tours/london-graffiti-and-street-art-tour/ (no affiliation). As a bonus you get some background, typically the guide is an artist that can point out more locations. Also the term "professional street art" kind of makes me shiver. And have you seen this? https://www.google.com/maps/d/viewer?mid=zTfE-q_5Z_0M.kasKtT95qNMI&hl=en

Comment: @mts I assume that there are hunderds of high-quality works in London at any given moment, which would be hard to cover by any single tour.

Comment: @mts but thanks for the link! I'd gladly accept it if you post it as an answer as I've decided to take the tour.

Comment: If anyone else had written this question, JonathanReez, you'd be saying "I'm voting to close this question because it's about art and cartography, not travel."... luckily for you other users have a more positive attitude.

Comment: Dear @user568458. I agree I've not been careful enough with my close votes lately. Sorry if I've offended you with my voting record :)

Comment: @JonathanReez can you please give the last needed reopen vote for the [London airports question](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/62718/how-long-does-it-take-to-get-into-london-from-its-airports). I've been waiting since Saturday to give the answerer a much-deserved bounty. Any longer and I'll forget. It's obstruction, not offense.

Comment: @user568458 done

Comment: I came here to ask something similar!
I really would love to see a real banksy at my next London trip in june!
So did you find any other maps?
what did you see at your trip?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While it's not a map, why don't you consider a tour such as [this free walking tour](http://www.freetoursbyfoot.com/london-tours/walking-tours/london-graffiti-and-street-art-tour/) (no affiliation, a quick google search will give more results).

I've taken a similar tour in NYC and was quite pleased. As a bonus over a map you get some background info on artists and tools, typically the guide is an artist that can point out more locations to you.

Answer (score 11):

Best I can think of is [Legal Walls](http://www.legal-walls.net), which maps graffiti locations around the world.

While you are in London, be sure to check out the [Leake Street Tunnel](http://www.legal-walls.net/walls/432) [ [images here](https://foursquare.com/v/leake-street-graffiti-tunnel/4ba7c51cf964a520c7b139e3/photos) ] - a three minute walk away from the London Eye, which was set up by Banksy as part of the Cans Festival in 2008. The tunnel used to form access for the now defunct Eurostar terminal at Waterloo station.

As I used to work on that street, I know that the artwork can last a little as 24 hours before the next artist sprays their work all over it.

Comment: I watch a moto-vlogger who stops in at that tunnel at least once a month; the thing is, every other tunnel in the city he revs up his bike to hear the tone of his exhaust, yet treats that place like a church or shrine, putters in as quietly as possible. :)

Answer (score 3):

A website called "[Street Art with Google Art Project](https://streetart.withgoogle.com/en/world-collection)" offers a great online map of graffiti around the world, including London:

[image]

The only problem is that the map is not too detailed, so it would take some walking around to find the actual location of each work.